Two pumps pulling water from same source
If I want to pull water with 2 pumps from the same pipe, it is recommended to install check valves so pumps don't interfere with each other when they run at the same time. Basically chat gpt said so :)
But I don't understand why and how does a check valve help. I understand that check valves let water flow into one direction only. So let's say I put 2 check valves, one before each pump. When pumps are running, they are sucking water, so it's impossible for water to go backwards anyway. And when they are not running, water is not going back because of the check valve from the end of the pipe. Or am I missing something?

Water flow/pressure will tend to fill the open spaces.  Water at a tee will want to go in both directions.  I like the keep it simple, this seems how to add difficulties.  Having a second backup pump is good.  Using both pumps together seems weird.

check valve is a good solution

You want to run 2 pumps...but why?  What is the desired outcome?  Perhaps there is a better solution .

RMDman I want to have 2 pressure switches. One for the house with tank & lower pressure and one for garden without tank and higher pressure. And each pressure switch needs a pump

One pump and a PRV for the house & pressure tank (well, probably need a small pressure tank at least on the garden side, too) will cost a lot less than 2 pumps, and not need double the power supply for pumping, too.

Does the output of the pumps also end up in the same pipe?
If so, a pump not running looks like a funny shaped bit of pipe, and water will happily flow in circles back to the intake of the pump that is running.
If you have one intake feeding two pumps, and two outputs that never join, the pump thaat is running will draw water back from the output of the pump that is not running. If there's no water in the output of that pump, the running pump will suck air through it. Depending on the pump design, that may damage it or cause it to stop pumping.
Check valves prevent these backwards flows.
